# How to write a theorem corresponding to an algorithm's proof of correctness?

Tags: correctness-proof

Let $X$ be an algorithm whose correctness supposed to be proved. What is **the best practic**e to write the corresponding theorem?

For example:

Theorem: Algorithm $X$ correctly computes its output.

Comment: This question is wayyyy too broad. There *may* be a reference question we should write here, but it may be a better idea to split into more specific parts. Examples: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/59964/98 https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/2152/98. Of related interest: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/29475/98 https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/13785/98

Comment: @Raphael: Thanks, but the question is not about the procedure to prove the correctness of an algorithm, but `how one should verbally compose the theorem which reflects that correctness`! My example does not seem to be so professional and mathematically fluent and standard.

Comment: "Best practice" is subjective / a matter of opinion, which isn't a good fit here; see our [help/dont-ask].  What exactly is your question?  In general the answer is you write a specification of what it means for the algorithm to be correct, then you state the claim that the algorithm meets this specification.  I find it hard to imagine that this is the kind of answer you are looking for, but it's hard for me to know what you *are* looking for.  Perhaps if you've done some research or considered some possible answers and rejected them it would help if you told us why you rejected them.

Comment: Since you are asking for the best practice method, can you comment on what methods you are familiar with? e.g. loop invariants